# Swift: keeping a strong reference to a weak variable

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, reference-counting

I have a class with a weak reference to its delegate. In a background operation, I need to set the delegate, perform an operation on the class, and then have the delegate released.

The code below works in Debug mode, but fails in Release mode, because in Release mode the delegate is released right away.

```
protocol DocumentDelegate:class { ... }

class MyDocument {
    weak var delegate:DocumentDelegate?

    func save() {
        assert(self.delegate =! nil)
    }
}

// Later:

// (#1) Using "var" does not work:
var delegate:DocumentDelegate? = InterimDelegate()

let document = MyDocument()

document.delegate = delegate

// Compiled in Release mode, at this time the delegate is already nil!
document.save()

delegate = nil


// (#2) Using "let" does work:
let delegate:DocumentDelegate = InterimDelegate()

let document = MyDocument()

document.delegate = delegate

// Compiled in Release mode, at this time the delegate is already nil!
document.save()
```

I assumed that the last instruction `delegate = nil` would cause the compiler to keep the delegate around until then (i.e. the "last" time the variable  is used). However, thinking about it, it does make sense that the compiler optimizes the code and releases  the delegate instance right away, since there are no other strong references.

However, I do not understand why the compiler does not behave the same way in the second case when using "let". Here as well the compiler could see that the delegate is not referenced via a strong reference anywhere else, but it does keep it around until the end of the block.

What would be a good way to think about this and what is a good way to keep a strong reference to the weak delegate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I wholeheartedly agree with Rob Napier’s analysis, for the sake of completeness, I should note that you can also make the lifetime of the object explicit:

```swift
let delegate = InterimDelegate()

withExtendedLifetime(delegate) {
    let document = MyDocument()
    document.delegate = delegate
    document.save()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is just a strong delegate. Get rid of `weak`, you don't mean it.

If you need an object to exist as long as you have a reference to it, and you plan to manually remove that reference at some point, that's a strong reference. The important thing for a delegate is that it at some point release its reference to avoid cycles. That's typically done with a weak reference because it makes things easy. But it can be done manually with strong reference. This is how [URLSession's delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411530-delegate) works, for example.

If you intend the delegate to always be released after `save`, however, you may want to set it to nil in `save`. That can be nicer than having the caller do it (and matches how URLSession works; it automatically releases its delegate when it completes).

Just to explain what's happening in your code, ARC is allowed to release a reference after its last use.

```
// Example 1

// delegate is a strong reference
var delegate:DocumentDelegate? = InterimDelegate()

let document = MyDocument()

// Last read of delegate.
document.delegate = delegate
// delegate is released here. `document.delegate` is weak,
// so object is deallocated and set to nil.

// Compiled in Release mode, at this time the delegate is already nil!
document.save()

// This assignment is a no-op. The system was allowed to set it
// to nil earlier, so this doesn't matter.
delegate = nil


// Example 2

// This creates a strong reference
let delegate:DocumentDelegate = InterimDelegate()

let document = MyDocument()

// Last read of delegate.
document.delegate = delegate
// delegate is released here. `document.delegate` is weak,
// so object is deallocated and set to nil.    

// Compiled in Release mode, at this time the delegate is already nil!
document.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation. I understand the difference between strong and weak references. In my case I actually want a weak reference to the delegate, because in the typical use case the delegate is owned by another object. Only in this specific case do I use the "interim" delegate. What I do not quite understand is the compiler optimization. If I declare the delegate via "let" it is not released until the block exits (so it is still around while saving) whereas via "var" it is reallocated after the last read.

Comment: There's no promise either way. The compiler is free to release it after the last read if it wants to, but it is not required to release it after its last read. `let` values are generally thought of as constant by the compiler, so if you said that the optimizer did not release it until the scope ended, that wouldn't surprise me. The compiler is also pretty aggressive about releasing objects, so if you told me it released immediately, that wouldn't surprise me either. There is no promised behavior.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Looks like using `withExtendedLifetime` will be the way to go to achieve predictable behavior.